# "Unknown option "--enable-libfaad" ERROR: libfaac not found" while configuring ffmpeg

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg

I trying to install this following these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion git-core checkinstall yasm texi2html libfaac-dev libfaad-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore4-dev zlib1g-dev
cd
mkdir ffmpeg-x264-avfilter
cd ffmpeg-x264-avfilter
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
cd x264
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=x264 --pkgversion "1:0.svn`date +%Y%m%d`+`git rev-list HEAD -n 1 | head -c 7`" --backup=no --default
cd ..
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/soc/libavfilter
cd libavfilter
./checkout.sh
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=ffmpeg-avfilter --pkgversion "4:0.5+svn`date +%Y%m%d`" --backup=no --default
```

I got these errors:

```
Unknown option "--enable-libfaad".
Unknown option "--enable-avfilter-lavf".
ERROR: libfaac not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors when running `apt-get install libfaac-dev`? Also, remove the unknown options. Also, please learn to indent your code properly with 4 spaces, then you don't have to do the backticks thing.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

Answer (score 23):

Well, install `libfaac` first. It seems there was an error doing so. Make sure `apt-get install libfaac-dev` works.

The proper instructions for installing FFmpeg and x264 [are here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall git libfaac-dev libgpac-dev \
  libjack-jackd2-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev \
  libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev \
  libxfixes-dev texi2html yasm zlib1g-dev
```

Then, for x264:

```
cd
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
./configure --enable-static
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=x264 --pkgversion="3:$(./version.sh | \
  awk -F'[" ]' '/POINT/{print $4"+git"$5}')" --backup=no --deldoc=yes \
  --fstrans=no --default
```

And for FFmpeg:

```
cd
git clone --depth 1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
  --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=ffmpeg --pkgversion="5:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --backup=no \
  --deldoc=yes --fstrans=no --default
hash x264 ffmpeg ffplay ffprobe
```

That's it — filters should be automatically included.

Comment: just a note, in the first apt-get install list, you can add `checkinstall`

Answer (score 3):

I found that in Ubuntu 12.04 libfaac-dev wasn't installable, so following these instructions (https://superuser.com/questions/467774/how-to-install-libfaac-dev) I enabled the multiverse repository:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Removing the hashes on the following lines to enable the repo:

```
deb http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
```

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev
```

That should solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

If your installing on ec2 ubuntu instance...

you must upgrade to this yasm, which isn't in the repos

.....

```
 install yasm

 wget http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz

 tar xvzf yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz

 cd yasm-1.2.0

 ./configure

 make && make install

 cd ..
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you are recommending this? The OP's error message has nothing to do with either yasm or ec2.

Comment: b/c as I was following this thread's instructions and I got to this --> Then, for x264: cd
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
./configure --enable-static .....  I couldn't proceed unless I did what I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have this error when you try to install ffmpeg then you must download lame from sourceforge

Open Terminal and write following

`wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.98.4/lame-3.98.4.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fffmpeg.zeranoe.com%2Fforum%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D5%26t%3D94&ts=1339140293&use_mirror=ignum`

After downloading try following one by one..

`tar -zxvf lame-3.98.4.tar.gz`

`cd lame-3.98.4`

`./configure`

`make`

`make install`

And you done.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the `libx264` error by installing `libavcodec-extra-53` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

Answer (score -1):

> #### Then, for x264:
>
> > cd
> >
> > git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
> >
> > cd x264
> >
> > ./configure --enable-static
> >
> > make
> >
> > sudo checkinstall --pkgname=x264 --pkgversion="3:$(./version.sh | \
> >      awk -F'[" ]' '/POINT/{print $4"+git"$5}')" --backup=no --deldoc=yes \
> >      --fstrans=no --default

This is **not** enough for a static build 
x264 must not link to other dynamic libraries, use the following to avoid problems when it comes to compiling ffmpeg:

## x264:

```
cd

clone git://git.videolan.org/x264

cd x264

./configure --enable-static 
--disable-opencl \ 
--disable-avs \ 
--disable-cli \ 
--disable-ffms \ 
--disable-gpac \ 
--disable-lavf \ 
--disable-swscale 

make

sudo checkinstall --pkgname=x264 --pkgversion="3:$(./version.sh | \ awk -F'[" ]' '/POINT/{print $4"+git"$5}')" --backup=no --deldoc=yes \ --fstrans=no --default
```